# Yolo v1 - what is the purpose of the confidence Ci?

Tags: yolo

[YOLO v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640) model predicts the confidence score $\hat{C_i}$ but I am not clear with the purpose of $\hat{C_i}$.

Definition of the confidence score in the [YOLO v1 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02640).

> [image]

$\hat{C_i}$ is used in the loss function as in the paper.

> [image]

It seems to me that $\hat{C_i}$ might be redundant because the confidence that the prediction is accurate can be judged by checking if the localization prediction `(x, y, w, h)` is close to the ground truth, which is done by calculating IOU. This is why I wonder if $\hat{C_i}$ is essential in YOLO v1.

The question is what role does $\hat{C_i}$ play and if we really need it?

#### Note

The question was re-written based on the feedback in the comment that the original question was hard to understand what it was asking.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your question "what would occur without?"  That is so ungrammatical as to present difficulties understanding what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Since yolov1 predicts two boxes per grid cell (containing an object or not), it needs a way to decide which boxes are useful (i.e. which ones are likely to contain an object). This is where the confidence score comes into play. By thresholding the predictions with a certain value of the confidence score, some predicted boxes are ignored, keeping only the ones that the network has associated to objects.

Comment: @JavierTG, thanks for the answer. I wonder the IOU of each bounding box using (x, y, w, h) could give such threshold. Or does confidence score gives if an object exists $Pr(Object)$ in the paper which IOU does not provide? So without Ci, YOLO may not identify if an object exists, hence the conditional probability P(Class|Object) would suffer?

Comment: @William, please let me know if the update makes better sense.

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in yolov1's paper (caption of Fig. 1): "*Our system (1) resizes [...] and (3) thresholds the resulting detections by the model’s **confidence***". For instance, let's consider two plausible predicted boxes at a certain grid cell. Box 1 has a predicted IOU of 0.01, while box 2 has a predicted IOU of 0.9. Given this, it is clear that we want to ignore box 1, and keep box 2 as detection since the latter is likely to contain an object while the former doesn't. The threshold on $\hat{C}_i$ (predicted IOU) is used to decide which boxes are ignored and which are kept as detections.

Comment: @JavierTG, thanks. Appreciate it.

Comment: @JavierTG, I posted an answer based on your input, but if you could post yours, I accept it as the answer as it came from you.

Comment: Close-voters: I believe questions like this should stay open, because the programming aspect is secondary to the statistical one, see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5985/1352.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Javier TG](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/258451/javier-tg), got the understanding about the confidence $\hat{C_i}$ .

$\hat{C_i}$ is used to calculate the class scores by multiplying with 20 class probabilities per cell which is then used to mitigate the multiple detection issue.

> However, some large objects or objects near the border of multiple cells can be well localized by multiple cells. Non-maximal suppression can be used **to fix these multiple detections**.

> [image]

> [image]

I think this may not be explained in detail in the paper, but found a good article [YOLO — ‘You only look once’ for Object Detection explained](https://medium.com/diaryofawannapreneur/yolo-you-only-look-once-for-object-detection-explained-6f80ea7aaa1e).

> Next, we multiply all these class score with bounding box confidence and get class scores for different bounding boxes. We do this for all the grid cells. That is equal to 7*7*2 = 98.
> [image]
> Now we have class scores for each bounding box(Tensor dimension=20*1). Now let us focus on the dog in the image. The dog score for the bounding boxes will be present in (1,1) of the tensor in all the bounding box scores. We will now set a threshold value of scores and sort them descendingly.
> [image]
> Now we will use Non-max suppression algorithm to **set score to zero for redundant boxes**.

In summary, multiple cells can detect the same dog in the image, but we do not want duplicate detections. And the confidence score $\hat{C_i}$ is the essential mechanism to avoid it.

To the comment:

> **"what would occur without" is so ungrammatical as to present difficulties understanding**.

Multiple detections of the same object **would occur without** $C_i$ that results in redundant detections. I am not sure why this is ungrammatical. Hope someone can explain.

Comment: Note that not only NMS is used to suppress redundant boxes. Previously, uncertain predictions (those with an estimated confidence below a certain threshold) are discarded. And next, NMS is applied on the remaining boxes. Otherwise a lot of the predicted boxes appearing in your second picture would not be suppressed.

Comment: @JavierTG, thanks a lot for the followup. Look into the process.